# Undefined control sequence \textquotesingle

Tags: symbols

I am new to latex.

I get the following error:

> Undefined control sequence. man1 = Person(\textquotesingle{}M\textquotesingle {}, 1, {[}2, 1... ...gle{}M\textquotesingle{}, 1, {[}2, 1{]})}

And the line in question is:

```
\texttt{man1 = Person(\textquotesingle{}M\textquotesingle{}, 1, {[}2, 1{]})}
```

Answer (score 21):

**Update Jan. 2021**: It has come to my attention that starting with the 2020/02/02 version of the LaTex2e format, it is no longer necessary to load the `textcomp` package in order to use the instruction `\textquotesingle`. For more information about the changes brought about by the 2020/02/02 version of LaTeX, see https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf.

---

(The answer I posted back in September 2014 follows. I suppose it is now mainly (purely?!) of historical relevance.)

You may have forgotten to load the [textcomp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package, which defines the macro `\textquotesingle`. With the package loaded, your code doesn't throw an error.

By the way, the curly braces after each `\textquotesingle` and around the square brackets aren't needed. I'd omit them, to reduce code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\texttt{man1 = Person(\textquotesingle M\textquotesingle, 1, [2, 1])}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to install this on RHEL?  There is no `texlive-latex-extra` package.

Comment: With the passage of time, `\textquotesingle` (and half a dozen other quote commands) work without needing any packages. I guess they have been added to the kernel.

Comment: @Cicada - Are you sure about this claim? If I try to compile `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \textquotesingle \end{document}` -- note that the `textcomp` package is *not* loaded -- on my system (MacTeX2019, all add-ins up to date), I get an "Undefined control sequence" message about `\textquotesingle`.

Comment: @Mico, quite right; the different engines give different results. Testing shows pdflatex generates the error still; it's OK in xelatex and lualatex. (Sometimes I forget people still do non-unicode or otherwise have to use pdflatex as their default engine: apologies.)