# Typewriter Apostrophe

Tags: symbols, typewriter, amssymb

Is there a method to create a typewriter apostrophe `\texttt{'}` with only basic Latex or `amssymb`?

The closest thing I've [found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202166/undefined-control-sequence-textquotesingle) requires the [`textcomp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package.

Comment: why archaic? `textcomp` is part of the core distribution so  `\textquotesingle` requiring `textcomp` is no different to say `\section` requiring `article`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle CTAN listed it in the obsolete section; I thought that meant something.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nothing wrong with it, but I'm still looking for a simple solution which doesn't require another package.  There's no universal math symbol which looks like a straight monospace dash? (I did check CTAN's list of symbols and came up pretty empty..)

Comment: see the text it says: that is the pre-latex2e version which is obsolete textcomp was adopted into the core latex2e distribution back in 1993 or so so that "new" version is not obsolete

Comment: textcomp is not "another package" is certainly more core than amsmath, if you object to textcomp, do you pbject to `\documentclass{article}` since article.cls and textcomp.sty are distributed in the same ctan upload to latex/base

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is all understood. My mistake on calling it obsolete; I removed the quip from the question. Still, I just wanted to be sure there was no simple alternative which did not require adding further packages beyond the ones I'm already using (which includes `amssymb`).

Comment: With the OT1 encoding (so without loading `fontenc`), the straight quote is available as `\texttt{\symbol{13}}`

Comment: @egreg Ahh; I am using T1 (with `fontenc` without `lmodern`). Does this change anything?

Comment: @kando So you load `fontenc` but don't want to load `textcomp`? Curious. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Actually, that's part of it. I use T1 universally and wondered how`textcomp` would affect it.

Comment: @kando In no way.

Comment: @egreg Cool.  Where can I find a list of symbol values which line up with \symbol{x}?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Does "adopted into the core" mean 'part of the kernel'? I can run `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}
\textquotesingle x\textquotesingle \end{document}` and get 'x' (under xelatex, with default LM font). I looked in `article.cls` and `size10.clo` and nothing in those were doing anything special, quote-wise (that I could see). Nothing else mentioned in the log.

Comment: Ahh, pdflatex generates the error; it's defined in xelatex and lualatex.

Comment: I mean that textcomp.sty is in the latex/base distribution so anyone who as latex has it, it is as much part of latex as say article class, it is not like other packages found on ctan that are extensions provided by users. @Cicada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason for avoiding `textcomp`. Anyway,

```
\texttt{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\symbol{13}}
```

produces the straight quote in typewriter type.

You can see the full set of characters in the OT1-encoded typewriter font with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{OT1}{\ttdefault}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}

\end{document}
```

[image]